# How to one-hot-encode an two dimensional matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have a huge numpy 2d array, each value is a category between 0 and 3:

```
[[3 1 0 ... 1]
...
 [2 0 1 ... 3]]
```

I want to one-hot-encode it (0 is `0 0 0 1`, 1 is `0 0 1 0`, etc), so the above will become:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 ... 0 0 1 0]
...
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ... 1 0 0 0]]
```

What will be the most efficient way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an `(M, N)` matrix, and your max value is `P` (`= 4`):

```
M = 6
N = 5
P = 4
mat = np.random.randint(P, size=(M, N))
```

First encode it as an `(M, N, P)` matrix of zeros and ones, using `mat` as the index in the last dimension:

```
encoded = np.zeros((M, N, P), dtype=int)
encoded[(*np.ogrid[:M, :N], (P - 1) - mat)]
```

Alternatively, use `np.put_along_axis`:

```
np.put_along_axis(encoded, (P - 1) - np.expand_dims(mat, -1), 1, axis=-1)
```

The data has the same order you want in memory already because numpy uses C order by default. You can just `reshape` to get the final result:

```
encoded.reshape(M, N * P)
```

Comment: Right interpreted it wrong... Just saw that the transformed arrays are concatenated.